# Python iterator that precomputes return (enqueue)

Tags: python, iterator, queue, multiprocessing, yield

I have a python iterator that solves a time-consuming task each iteration. It would be nice if the return values of the iterator could be precomputed in the background, such that when the iterator is called, the result can be yielded right away.

eg

```
import numpy as np

def sample_iterator():
    while True:
        x = np.random.rand(int(1e8)).mean()
        yield x
```

Comment: please tell me why the question is unclear, such that I can edit and improve it, when voting it down!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a iterator (`precomputing_iterator`) that takes an iterator (`sample_iterator`) as input. `precomputing_iterator` precomputes the return values of `sample_iterator`. When `precomputing_iterator` is created the precomputation of return values of `sample_iterator` is started right away. The return values are saved on a `multiprocessing.Queue` object. If there are values on the queue, `precomputing_iterator` can yield them right away.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import numpy as np
import time

def sample_iterator():
    while True:
        x = np.random.rand(int(1e8)).mean()
        yield x

def precomputing_iterator(iterator, maxsize = 5):

    def enqueue(q):
        while True:
            q.put(iterator.next())

    q = Queue(maxsize = maxsize)
    p = Process(target=enqueue, args=(q,))
    p.start()

    while True:
        yield q.get()

i1 = sample_iterator()
i2 = precomputing_iterator(i1)

t = time.time()
i2.next()
print "execution time:", time.time() - t

time.sleep(3)

t = time.time()
i2.next()
print "execution time:", time.time() - t
```

Here for me the first execution time is 1.4 seconds (queue is empty. No return values precomputed). The second execution time is 0.00031 seconds (the precomputed result is just returned)